# jQuery looping .fadeIn and .fadeOut of p tags within div one at a time

Tags: jquery, loops, this, fadein

The code below successfully fades in one testimonial for 6 seconds, waits 3 seconds, and then fades it out and moves on to the next. Once it reaches the third testimonial it jumps back to the first. This is exactly what I want but on my actual site I have more than three testimonials and in the future may be adding more. I don't want to have to go back and add a new function every time I add a new testimonial. I tried for some time to get this to work using "this" and .next() but failed. I'm hoping someone could make this much more efficient by looping it and getting it to move to the next p tag within the container without calling a new function every time. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Note: I know there are similar questions but none of them were quite the same and the answers are sub par.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<style>
#tml-container p { display: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tml-container">
    <p id="one">Testimonial 1</p>
    <p id="two">Testimonial 2</p>
    <p id="three">Testimonial 3</p>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function doFade() {
        $("#one").fadeIn(6000,function() {
            $("#one").fadeOut(6000).delay(3000);
            setTimeout(fadeTwo,6000);
        });
    }

    function fadeTwo() {
        $("#two").fadeIn(6000,function() {
            $("#two").fadeOut(6000).delay(3000);
            setTimeout(fadeThree,6000);
        });
    }

    function fadeThree() {
        $("#three").fadeIn(4000,function() {
            $("#three").fadeOut(6000).delay(3000);
            setTimeout(doFade,6000);
        });
    }
    doFade();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While you're using jQuery, may I suggest hiding your elements with `$('p').hide();` to keep the content visible to users without jQuery as a fallback.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a very simple solution:

```
function fade($ele) {
    $ele.fadeIn(6000).delay(3000).fadeOut(6000, function() {
        var $next = $(this).next('p');
        // if there is a following `p` element, it is faded in
        // otherwise start from the beginning by taking
        // the parent's first child
        fade($next.length > 0 ? $next : $(this).parent().children().first());
   });
};  

fade($('#tml-container > p').first());
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JQ3uh/)

---

**Reusable plugin version:**

Instead of iterating over the children of a certain element, it iterates over the selected elements.

```
(function($) {
    var default_config = {
        fadeIn: 3000,
        stay: 3000,
        fadeOut: 3000
    };

    function fade(index, $elements, config) {
        $elements.eq(index)
          .fadeIn(config.fadeIn)
          .delay(config.stay)
          .fadeOut(config.fadeOut, function() {
              fade((index + 1) % $elements.length, $elements, config);
          });
    }

    $.fn.fadeLoop = function(config) {     
        fade(0, this, $.extend({}, default_config, config));
        return this;
    };

}(jQuery));
```

Usable as:

```
$('#tml-container > p').fadeLoop({fadeIn: 6000, stay: 3000, fadeOut: 6000});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nXjBR/)

Comment: *Very* nice answer! Especially the plugin stuff. Great, great stuff going on here.

Comment: Works like a charm! That jsFiddle demo is nice too. Never seen that site before. Much appreciated for taking the time to answer but if you or anyone else wouldn't mind explaining the following the line.
fade($next.length > 0 ? $next : $(this).parent().children().first());

Comment: @Justin: Consider using the plugin version, as it is easier to reuse and not that prone to changes of your HTML structure. I will add some comments regarding that line. The `x ? y : z` construct is the *conditional operator*. It returns `y` if `x` is true, else `z`. `$next.length` tells you how many elements have been selected by `$(this).next('p')`. If none have been selected, then there is no following `p` element and we have to continue from the beginning, so we take the parent's first child instead. This assumes that the first child is actually the next one we want to fade in (as it is the

Comment: case in your example). The plugin in version is more flexible, it just loops over all selected elements.

Comment: @FelixKling Very nice! Thanks for the plugin and the additional explanations. That helps a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Changed a self developed Plugin to meet your requirements,
didn't test it fully though.

Should at least show you how to set something like this up properly.

Hope this helps :)

```
(function($){
    $(function(){
        $('#tml-container').testimonialFader();
    });

    $.fn.testimonialFader = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            var $par = $(this),
            $testimonials = $par.children('p'),
            $current = $testimonials.first();

            $testimonials.not(':first').hide();

            $testimonials.on('testimonialReady.testimonialFader', wait);
            $testimonials.on('waitComplete.testimonialFader', showNext);

            $current.trigger('testimonialReady.testimonialFader');

            function wait(e){
                $current.trigger('waitStart.testimonialFader');
                setTimeout(
                    function(){
                            $current.trigger('waitComplete.testimonialFader');
                        },
                        6000
                );
            }
            function showNext(){
                $current.trigger('testimonialChange.testimonialFader');
                if($testimonials.length > 1){
                    var $next = $current.next();
                    if($next.length == 0){
                        $next = $testimonials.first();
                    }
                    $current.fadeOut(800);
                    $next.fadeIn(800, 
                        function(){
                            $next.trigger('testimonialReady.testimonialFader');
                        }
                    );
                    $current = $next;
                }
            }

        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```