# What are your best practices for looping timed jquery function

Tags: jquery, loops, timing

As I work on looping with jQuery I'm really puzzled how to pass the values and start over.

My project is a "simple" testimonial rotator.

```
<div id="testimonials">
    <div class="testimonial">
        <p>You're great!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial">
        <p>Thanks a lot!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="testimonial">
        <p>Rock on!</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            function fade() {
                $('.testimonial').hide();
                var t = $('.testimonial').length;
                alert(t);
                for( var i = 1; i <= t; i++){
                    function slideit(){
                       var i = i;
                       $('.testimonial.nth-child(' + i + ')').show('slow');
                       $('.testimonial.nth-child(' + i + ')').hide('slow').delay(2000);
                    }
                    slideit();
                }
            }
            fade();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, I'm stuck. Pointers to get over the hump?

Comment: `$('.testimonial.nth-child[' + i + ']')` should be `$('.testimonial:nth-child(' + i + ')')`

Comment: Note, if you're just looking for an elegant jQuery script that addresses this function, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8616480/497438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)

```
var i = 0, // index of element to show
    t = $('.testimonial'), // elements
    max = t.length; // max elements
function fade() {
    t.eq(i).show('slow'); // we show current element
    t.not(':eq('+i+')').hide('slow'); // we hide others
    if(++i >= max) i=0; // we increment index and if we go over max, we reset index
}
window.setInterval(fade,3000); // we call fade every 3 seconds
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zf5Wb/

Comment: Ahh. Now, we're using javascript. I often rely on jQuery to do my thinking for me, forgetting how straight javascript might be simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Shikiryu suggested.

Change the code from

```
$('.testimonial.nth-child[' + i + ']')
```

to

```
$('.testimonial:nth-child(' + i + ')')
```

Comment: which ever answer you found useful tick the answer or If you have found out solution yourself Please post your answer. This helps people dropping into this page find the answer immediately :)

Comment: I was just letting it breathe a bit. I get annoyed when folks don't check the solutions too.