# Animation text fade-in other text

Tags: css, animation, fadein

I was trying to make an animation with this HTML:

```
<div class="client-quote home">
<p>
<a href="/klanten.html">
“Flexibel, meedenken, snel schakelen, creatief, kwaliteit … zo ervaar ik NPN. Een fijne partner, die kennis van zaken en de branche heeft.”
</a>
</p>
<p>
</p>
<p class="center-text">
<a href="/klanten.html">
<em>
Cindy Bastiaansen, Commercieel Medewerker, Healthypharm BV &amp; Neocare BV
</em>
</a>
</p>
<p>
</p>
</div>
```

I want to change both of the text with fade-in and fade-out.

How could I do this?
Using `:after` and `:before` with transitions?

Using the jQuery on comments:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
function doFade() {
    jQuery(".client-quote").fadeIn(1000,function() {
        jQuery(".client-quote").delay(18000).fadeOut(1000);
        setTimeout(fadeTwo,19000);
    });
}

function fadeTwo() {
    jQuery(".client-quote2").fadeIn(1000,function() {
        jQuery(".client-quote2").delay(18000).fadeOut(1000);
        setTimeout(fadeThree,19000);
    });
}

function fadeThree() {
    jQuery(".client-quote3").fadeIn(1000,function() {
        jQuery(".client-quote3").delay(18000).fadeOut(1000);
        setTimeout(doFade,19000);
    });
}
doFade();
```

> });

Now is correct.
Just the time, i dont understand how it goes.
If i want to let all the text to stay 20 seconds, i have to give the fadein and fadeout to 20000 ?
And if i want that the transaction spend just 1 second to do completly between one and two?

EDIT: Changed correctly.
Now, it need 1 second to show the first, then, wait 18 seconds doing nothing, and in another second, it hide, and appear the second.

Animation duration: 60 second.

Comment: What event are you trying to animate on? Like what causes the text to fade?

Comment: I want to change the text for another one, with the same structure.
The text i don´t kwow which one, just change to other, thats all.
The cause is time, every.. 40 seconds.. i don´t care, i just want to know how is the best way to do it.

Comment: Check this answer it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616395/jquery-looping-fadein-and-fadeout-of-p-tags-within-div-one-at-a-time

Comment: @UsmanArshad yeah it could help me, but the jquery dont works and i dont know why, i edit the code to show how i was doing

Comment: Ok first of all, i was using # instead of .

And $ instead of jQuery.

Comment: @UsmanArshad Any idea how works the timers?

Comment: Please check the answer and demo below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The animation was done with jQuery:

Used the properties: `setTimeOut` `fadeOut` `fadeIn`

animation.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    function doFade() {
        jQuery(".client-quote").fadeIn(1000,function() {
            jQuery(".client-quote").delay(18000).fadeOut(1000);
            setTimeout(fadeTwo,19000);
        });
    }

    function fadeTwo() {
        jQuery(".client-quote2").fadeIn(1000,function() {
            jQuery(".client-quote2").delay(18000).fadeOut(1000);
            setTimeout(fadeThree,19000);
        });
    }

    function fadeThree() {
        jQuery(".client-quote3").fadeIn(1000,function() {
            jQuery(".client-quote3").delay(18000).fadeOut(1000);
            setTimeout(doFade,19000);
        });
    }
    doFade();
});
```

Animation duration: 60 seconds.